# Explicit std::exception_ptr conversion to bool does not exist... VS2010 bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

Installed VS2010 + SP1 to build homebrew OpenCV 3.4. Got error in core module async.cpp(112):

```
111 #if CV__EXCEPTION_PTR
112 if(has_exception && exception)
113 {...}
117 #endif
```

has_exception is bool, exception is std::exception_ptr. Error: C2677.

Made simple test based on example in (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception_ptr/):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <exception>
int _tmain (int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  std::exception_ptr p;
  bool b1, b2;
  b1 = (bool)p;
  b2 = static_cast<bool>(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Both casts fail to debug with C2440.
Based on docs(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) exception_ptr should be "contextually convertible" and explicitly convertable.
I guess it has something to do with my environment, but i have no idea how to correct it.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and the full error message?

Comment: Edited code fragment as the rules demand. Saldy compile error is in russian, so i can only compile "full error message" by hand: error C2440: cannot convert from 'std::exception_ptr' to 'bool'. same at lines 6 and 7 of the example.

Comment: Do note that MSVS2010 was released before C++11 was even standardized and has very limited C++11 support.  You need at least MSVS2015 update 3 for full C++11 compliance.  That said, MSVS2019 is a available for free and if you are going to upgrade, you should use that since you'll get access to C++14 and C++17 features.

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr), `std::exception_ptr` indeed should be contextually convertible to `bool`. If it doesn't work with your compiler then this is a compiler defect. Though VS2010 is rather old and is unlikely to be fixed.

You can work around it by comparing the pointer with default-constructed `std::exception_ptr`, which is a null pointer:

```
if (ptr != std::exception_ptr()) {
    // ptr is not null
}
```

Comment: Good point. VS2010 predates the 2011 C++ standard obviously, so you can't expect compliance with it.

Comment: VS2010 has some features of C++11, but they are incomplete. And it would be rather great if they've adopted "All or nothing" approach, but they kinda created exception_ptr type, but didn't declared nor implemented operator bool(). I checked this example with some colleagues(just to see if my vs install was intact) and every variant of v100 platform had the same result.